# CSS reverse button active animation on release

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a 3D-style button that moves down 4 pixels when active, and moves back when inactive. The push down animation works perfectly, but what bugs me is the instant jump back. How could I reverse the animation after button release? I want this with pure CSS, if possible.

CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes movedown {
    from {
        top: 0px;
    }
    to {
        top: 4px;
    }
}

@keyframes movedown {
    from {
        top: 0px;
    }
    to {
        top: 4px;
    }
}

.btn {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    border: none;
    outline: 0;
    background: #BDBDBD;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 0px #848484;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #0f0f0f;
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1em;
    transition: all .15s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .15s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .15s ease-in-out;
}
.btn:hover {
    background: #D8D8D8;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 0px #848484, inset 0px 0px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
.btn:active {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #d8d8d8, inset 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    animation: movedown .15s ease-in-out 0s forwards;
    -webkit-animation: movedown .15s ease-in-out 0s forwards;
    background: #848484;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/StashCat/b4BE6/)

Comment: You shouldn't be using animations for this. Transitions exists for this exact reason.

Comment: Can't understand why you used animation here, looks like you don't really understand when to use which one. This edit keeps using animation http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/b4BE6/1/ but as I said you should use transition for this, it should work OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is very rarely a reason to use CSS animations.  Stick with transitions.

```
.btn {
    transition: height 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

.btn {
    top: 4px;
}
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that height controlled the top property. I tried to do a workaround for that. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: It doesn't directly, but when the top changes, it's likely the height changes as well.  I think you might be able to transition top as well, not sure.